# Custom Back button flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi guys i want to chage the beheviour of exiting back button funcionality of Android's defaul bottom bar. In my app if i press the "arrow" it close the application but i want to it come back to previous screen. I don't know how to do it i tried with appBar but using onPressed () appears a black screen. Altrought my mind the best and elegant solution is to change the "arrow" beheviour and it also has to work for IOS. How can i do it?

This is the appBar code

```
appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          color: red,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the behaviour of the bottom back button of app you can use onWillPop

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => backPress(),
  child: Scaffold(
......
```

and backpress function decides what to do instead

```
Future<bool> backPress() async {
  print("hellp");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i tried to use this but when the button is clicked appears a black screen and it doesn't go to the previuous screen, btw the debug print works i don't know how...```Future<bool> backPress() async {
    print("test");
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return false;
  }```

Comment: are you sure there is another page in navigator stack?

Comment: I fixed that, navigator.pop isnt' correct beacuse it doesn't redirect the new screen direct to the sidebard that redirect at homepage that is a dashboard. So The first choise that the user do, the back button will alway bring to the dashboard screen and i used this line of code `BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc(context).add(NavigationEvents.HomePageClickedEvents);` instead of  `Navigator.pop(context);`